Muscle spasms/twitching on eyelids when meditating
I have tried to meditate regularly, and closed my eyes. However, as I kept my eyes closed, not even a few minutes would pass until muscles of my eyelids and surrounding regions began to twitch/spasm. I guess it strains my muscles. How should I deal with this, as it makes concentration quite difficult?

Spasm is caused by either mental stress, mental over-exertion  or a physical neurological disorder.
If the spasm is caused by mental stress or mental over-exertion, it is probably best to keep the eyes open in a natural way, which will also allow any tension around the eyes to resolve itself. Allow the eyes to be natural until they close themselves.
The Buddha taught to meditate with balanced effort, as instructed in the Sona Sutta.
The primary quality to be developed in Buddhist meditation is letting go (surrender; vossagga) rather than brute exertion. The Buddha taught mindfulness ripens as letting go (end of MN 118).
